# Quantum Theory of Paramagnetism

Tags: solid-state-physics

The energy levels of the system in a magnetic field are

$$ \ (1) \ U=-\vec \mu \cdot \vec B$$

As per the Kittel's Solid State physics which has confused me since, Now,

$$ \ \ \ \ \ (2) \ U=m_Jg\mu_BB$$
I know that

$$ \ \ \ (3) \ \mu=-g\mu_B\vec J , $$

but the second step has still left me perplexed. How, the second step originates from the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you make a mistake. The operator

(i) $ \ \hat U = −\hat {\vec {\mu}} \cdot \vec B = −g\ \mu _B \ \hat {\vec J} \cdot \vec B$

doesn't give energy levels, but an additional energy term in the Hamiltonian. Let's take for simplicity the direction $z$ of our system of axes in the direction of $\vec B$. Then my formula (i) becomes

(ii) $ \ \hat U = −g\ \mu _B \hat {J_z} B$

But we know what are the eigenvalues of the projection operator $\hat {J_z}$, these values are discrete and equal to $m_z$. Thus the eigenvalues of the operator (ii) are
those given by your formula (2),

(iii) $ \ E = −g\ \mu _B \ m_z B . $

Thus, the energy that a system has in the absence of the magnetic field, is split in the presence of the field into $2j + 1$ sublevels at a distance

(iv) $ \Delta E = g\ \mu _B B$

from one another.

Comment: Basically, my confusion is how from $U=g\mu_B\vec J.\vec B$, it results $U=g\mu_Bm_JB$ because $\vec J=m_J \hbar \hat{z}$

Comment: @RoshanShrestha : I am sorry I had an omission in my formula. Please look now, I changed my answer according to your comment.